# Google Apps Script Regex Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am getting some odd behaviour using regex in google apps script and I'm not sure if I'm just missing something obvious.

```
var text = "I am testing this IMAGING";
var regex = new RegExp('(?:Image)\s*','g');
var capture = regex.exec(text);
while (capture != null) {
  Logger.log("captured: "+capture[0]);
  capture = regex.exec(text);
}
```

In this case, it matches to "I" 3 times. Why? Setting the regex to "(?:Image) ?" produces the same result, and replacing the " " with anything else also produces the same result.

If I change the regex to any of the following they all no matches as expected:

- "(?:Image) +"
- "(?:Image)"
- "(Image) *"
- "(?:Image *)"

I thought that a non capturing group should have absolutely no impact in this situation. What am I missing here? Hopefully I've just made a dumb mistake.

Comment: `\s*` in your case is parsed as `s*`, zero or more `s` chars. In general, do not use non-capturing groups in GAS regex because they are not implemented correctly. If you use `'Image\\s*'` it will work as expected.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks! Do you have a link on more information about the non capturing groups in GAS?

Comment: No, it just seems they are totally broken, and the behavior is not defined when you use them. Only use them when you really must and test before using. Also, capturing groups can still be used, too, in most situations.

Comment: I found an issue for it here:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763521